# How to export Firestore subcollection data to CSV

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I'm trying to export subcollection of a firestore collection to a CSV file with the following code.

The npm used for this is "json2csv"

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);
const json2csv = require("json2csv").parse;
exports.csvJsonReport = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
    const db = admin.firestore();
    const data = db.collection("collectionname").doc().collection("subcollection") //collection name ,documentid, subcollection
    return data.get().then((querySnapshot) => {
        var object = {}
        var jsondata = [];
        querySnapshot.forEach(doc => {
            object = doc.data();
            object['docid'] = doc.id; // must add this line after doc.data
            console.log("objectbefore", object)
            jsondata.push(object);
            console.log("objectafter", object)
            console.log(jsondata);
        });
        const csv = json2csv(jsondata);
        response.setHeader(
            "Content-disposition",
            "attachment; filename=files.csv"//file name.csv
        );
        response.set("Content-Type", "text/csv");
        return response.status(200).send(csv)
    }).catch((err) => {
        return console.log(err);
    });
});
```

But the result that I get in the output CSV file is only the collection without the inner subcollections.

is it possible to export subcollection data in this method? If not, how can I export subcollection data to CSV?

edit #1: code is updated. This is the error I get
Error: Data should not be empty or the "fields" option should be included

Comment: Can you post your collections model? I suggest you to start from basics. Firstly let's convert your functions to `async/await`. Secondly let's just return subcollection data to the response, instead of exporting it to csv file. If you are able to do 1-2 steps, then it is easy to export data to csv.

Answer (score 2):

Queries in Firestore are shallow, meaning that when you query the `collectionname` collection you get the documents within this collection but you **DON'T** get the documents within the subcollections.

You'll have to query each sub-collection, one by one, in order to get the documents they contains and add their content to your CSV.

In case you don't know the names of those subcollections (i.e. they were created by the users while using your app and not by the database architect while designing the data model) you will find in the following [article](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-list-all-subcollections-of-a-cloud-firestore-document-17f2bb80a166) a method for listing all subcollections of a Firestore document with a Cloud Function (*disclaimer, I'm the article author*).

Comment: I used this article link,but getting an error.

Error: Data should not be empty or the "fields" option should be included

Comment: Please add your new code to your question (edit the question and add it at the bottom).

Comment: I added my new code,kindly check my code Renaud Tarnec

Comment: If I had enough rep to downvote I would, because your article is behind a Medium blog paywall.

Comment: @BenjiA. You can create a free account in Medium, see https://help.medium.com/hc/en-us/articles/225168028-Using-Medium