# subcollection not getting exported through Firestore export cloud function

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

Below is my cloud function for taking Firestore export to a GCP bucket. I am trying to pass the CollectionIDs name through 'collectionsToBackup' const which I am creating by appending the current_date to the name as my subcollection names are of the format: sub_collection_name_yyyymmdd. The function deploys however when its executed, it does not take the export of my subcollection: most_valuable_items_yyyymmdd for that day. Could someone help me please identify what could be wrong with my function?

**Code:**

```
const firestore = require('@google-cloud/firestore');
const client = new firestore.v1.FirestoreAdminClient();

const bucket = 'gs://BUCKET_NAME'
const date_ob = new Date();
const date = ("0" + date_ob.getDate()).slice(-2);
const month = ("0" + (date_ob.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2);
const year = date_ob.getFullYear();
const new_date= (year + month + date);

const collectionsToBackup= ("'" + "most_valuable_items" + "_" + new_date + "'");


exports.scheduledFirestoreBackup = (event, context) => {
  const databaseName = client.databasePath(
   // process.env.GCLOUD_PROJECT,
   "f-2",
    '(default)'
  );



return client
    .exportDocuments({
      name: databaseName,
      outputUriPrefix: bucket,
      collectionIds: [collectionsToBackup]
    })
    .then(responses => {
      const response = responses[0];
      console.log(`Operation Name: ${response['name']}`);

      return response;
    })
    .catch(err => {
      console.error(err);
    });
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem seems related to the querying and return of information with Firestore. As explained in this other similar case from the Community [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59855302/how-to-export-firestore-subcollection-data-to-csv), you will need to consider the limit of the queries in Firestore.

This limit is related to the possibility and functions that would allow you to query the subcollections, so they are sent to your bucket. Querying in Firestore is a shallow process, where, unfortunately, you can't return the whole collection and its own subcollections at once. It will be needed for you to read every subcollection, so you have its data as well as the parent collection.

So, to summarize, it's not about your code being wrong, but about changing the way you are reading your data - both collections and subcollections - so you load the data and then, send it over to the bucket. This answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59856599/12767257) clarifies more on possibilities.

Let me know if the information clarified your doubts!

Comment: @ gso_gabriel : My collection name is certain. Its 'most_valuable_items_20200706' for today's data. It will be 'most_valuable_items_20200707' for my export operation tomorrow. The export works fine if i explicitly mention the sub_collection name in my collectionIDs, but it does not work if I try to pass it through a const: collectionsToBackup.  collectionIds: ['most_valuable_items_20200706'], works perfectly.But I need to pass the values of collectionIds through some variable like collectionsToBackup (in this case) as the date part of my sub_collection name keeps changing daily.How do I do it?